# Simple partial derivative with optimization function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, partial-derivative

I have the following equation
$$L= \sum_{t=0}^{\infty}E_{0}\beta^{t}\left( \log c_t +\phi \log \left( 1-h_{t}\right)\right)+\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}E_{0}\beta^{t}\left[\lambda_{t}\left( (1+r_{t})a_{t}+w_{t}h_{t}+div_{t}-a_{t+1}-c_{t}\right) \right]$$

I want to find partial derivative which is equal to:

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial a_{t+1}}=-E_{0}\lambda_{t}+\beta^{t}E_{0}\left[ \lambda_{t+1}(1+r_{t+1})\right]$$

Question is how did we derive this result? I can not see e.g. $r_{t+1}$ in original function. Thus my question is what transformations were applied to achieve such a  result in a simplified form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think that given

$$
S(a) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(\lambda a_k-\mu a_{k+1})
$$

we have

$$
S(a) = \lambda a_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\lambda-\mu)a_k
$$

then

$$
\frac{\partial S}{\partial a_k} = \left\{\begin{array}{rcl}\lambda & & k = 0\\
\lambda-\mu& & k > 0\end{array}\right.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Take first order condition of $a_{t+1}$ in the objective function. Then flip the time index from t to t+1 in the objective function for all variable then take FOC. again for the $a_{t+1}$. Then you will get two equations for the same FOC. Then rest is simple algebra.
Clearly you will have $-E_0β^tλt=E_0β^{t+1}λ_{t+1}[1+r_{t+1}]$ equality, in which left hand side is FOC of given Lagrange, right hande side is FOC of equation after flipped from t to $t_{t+1}$.

Comment: Put braces `\{ \}` around your subscripts so that the whole of $(t+1)$ is a subscript.

Comment: @user466463 I think I need more explanation than that. Could you please be a little bit more specific as to what I need to do to obtain this result futhermore why do we need to flip the time index?

Comment: because you have $a_{t}$ and $a_{t+1}$ in the model at the same time. Since the series also start from $t=0$ which is including $a_{t+1}$ then you have to consider that too.

Comment: To make more simple let's take $t=1$ then you are asked to take FOC $a_{2}$. When you start plugging each time index from $0$ to $/infinity$ you will see that we will have $a_{2}$ twice in the all summation since it the variable $a$ is given with two time index, which is spanning also given period.